# how to play/preview video before uploading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have used images uploading preview using jquery and want to preview a video as well, but not getting any clue regarding. Have you any solution regarding. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

image preview is working fine

```
      function readURL(input) {
                  $('#previewHolderalbumList').hide();
                  $('#previewHolderalbum').show();
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                        $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
           }
       }
       $("#fileID").change(function() {
           readURL(this);
       });
```

Ragards,

Sonu Sindhu

Comment: @Triode Yehh I think my googling is too week..Thanks for your help